# How to show two values on the same layer using tm_text?

Tags: r, tmap

I am currently trying to show the values of different variables on the same map.

Below is my code:

```
tm_shape(pv_malay_merge) + 
  tm_fill(col = "Exposure", n = 10, title = "Policyholders' Exposure",
          palette = rev(brewer.pal(n = 4, "RdYlGn"))) +
  tm_borders(lwd = 0.5) +
  tm_text(text = "NAME_1", size = 0.5) +
  tm_shape(malay_merge) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "Exposure")
```

The code above results in:

[image: Malaysia map]

After that I try to change it to:

```
tm_shape(pv_malay_merge) + 
  tm_fill(col = "Exposure", n = 10, title = "Policyholders' Exposure",
          palette = rev(brewer.pal(n = 4, "RdYlGn"))) +
  tm_borders(lwd = 0.5) +
  tm_text(text = c("NAME_1", "Exposure"), size = 1) +
  tm_shape(malay_merge) +
  tm_bubbles(size = "Exposure")
```

Notice the change in `tm_text()` function. This results in:

[image: two Malaysia maps showing different values]

Any suggestion on combining the maps?

Comment: Including both into one map, would make the map hard to read imo. Furthermore: a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) would make it a lot easier for others to help you.

Comment: btw: maybe try with two separate calls for `tm_text`?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus The values will overlap with each other if we separate `tm_text`, I have tried it previously by creating two layers

Comment: You can use the `xmod` and the `ymod` parameters to adjust the position of the labels.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Thank you for your suggestion! I will try it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have more than one `tm_text` layers in one group, so you need two layer groups, e.g.:

```
tm_shape(pv_malay_merge) + 
  tm_text(text = "NAME_1", size = 0.5) +
tm_shape(pv_malay_merge) + 
  tm_text(text = "Exposure", size = 0.5)
```

To prevent occlusion, you could use `ymod` for one of them, as already suggested.

Why are the bubbles not visible? They should work better than text labels imo.